# Range taking with variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
VarRange  = Cells(1, 3).Address(True, False)

Range (VarRange1 : VarRange20 )
```

.... Where the `VarRange` contain the address of the column (Eg column B).

I'm expecting:   `Range (B1:B20)`

It's showing me error. Please help me

Comment: Dim Rng As Range

Comment: Set Rng = Worksheets("SheetName").Range("B1:B20)

Comment: Rng is the variable which will store the excel ranges.

Comment: What error? Anyway, of course it is. You declared one variable called `VarRange`, not 2 different ones called `VarRange1` and `VarRange20`. If you want to concatenate strings, then you need to use the `&` operator. You can't just write whatever you want and expect the interpreter to know what should be treated as code and what should be treated as strings. I don't know how `Address()` works, but you want _something_ like `Range(VarRange & "1:" & VarRange & ":20")` if `VarRange` holds the string `"B"`. But anyway, there are various much better ways to do this.

Comment: (um, remove the 2nd `:` in my example... I did say _something_ like :P)

Comment: Thanks... Its working now...

Answer (score 2):

`VarRange  = Cells(1, 3).Address(True, False)` will return a string like "C$1" because you specify row 1 and column 3. `Cells(3, 1).Column` would return 3 which Excel can understand as referring to column C. Therefore,

```
VarRange = Cells(1, 3).Column
MsgBox Range(Cells(1, VarRange), Cells(20, VarRange)).Address
```

would return $C$1:$C$20